# Android animated pixelation

Tags: android, bitmap, 2d, pixelate

I'm working on a game that obscures part of image, player then guesses what's hidden and finally the obscured part is revealed, so player can see if he guessed correctly.

At the moment I just draw a black box above the obscured part, but it would be nice if I could pixelate the obscured area to a huge pixel size, then decrease the pixelation size until the image is clearly visible, in an animation.

Is it possible to somehow utilize Android's support for animations (I have used it in one game, to animate on screen stuff), or would I need to implement this entirely on my own using some kind of timer and drawing on Canvas myself? Or is there something handy that will help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for a possible solution: use BitmapFactory to get a sample of your image that's smaller than the original, and blow it up to create a "pixelated" version. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

Comment: but I'd still like to animate this somehow, so I'd need to create the bitmap with decreasing sample sizes to go from totally pixelated to clear, right?

Comment: Exactly. Get much more complex than this and you're probably better off exploring your OpenGL options.